# Unusual issue with vector use

Tags: c++, vector

I was trying to write a program and I encountered some problem with `vector`. I have a logic where the values of the `vector` are to be compared at every iteration of the loop. So I initialize the vector and I push one element to each of the vector. Now since I have one element in both of these vectors, I should be able to compare and iterate as the following code should do, but it isn't. There might be a bug, but its difficult to find.

```
int M = 3; // I am passing values of M and N to this function
int N = 3; 
std::vector<int> X;
std::vector<int> Y;
X.push_back(1);
Y.push_back(1);
int x = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= M; j++){
        if((X[x] <= i) && (Y[x] <= j)){
            if (x > 0){
                X.push_back(i);
                Y.push_back(j);
                x = x + 1;
            }
            else{
                X[0] = 1;
                Y[0] = 1;
                x = x + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++){
    cout << X[i] << "; " << Y[i] << endl;
}
```

I get the following output with the above program.

```
`1; 1`
```

But I need to produce this.

```
`1; 1`
`1; 2`
`2; 2`
```

Comment: what is the expected result? What happens instead?

Comment: Could you include the declarations of N and M?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior*.

When `x` is zero you don't push a new entry into the vectors, you do however increase `x` and the next iteration you access `X[1]` and `Y[1]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: that means inner `if else` should be removed and some other construct should be considered to be replaced with?  because I thought of making some changes but each of them fail.

Comment: @mozart One other thing that stands out is that `X[0]` and `Y[0]` already are `1`, so those assignments aren't needed. I don't really know exactly what you try to accomplish, so can't say _how_ you should change the algorithm.

Comment: I have edited the question with requirements. The problem is that if I don't use the inner `if else`, the output produced is like 

`1; 1`
`1; 1`
`1; 2`
`2; 2`

but I want this

`1; 1`
`1; 2`
`2; 2`

Comment: @DanielFrey it won't increment the value of x

Comment: @Mozart: Change the `if` to `if(x>0 || i>1 || j>1)` and drop the `else` branch.